# JDBC Single connection pooling with different application names?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I've a Java Web application that currently consists of:

- multiple live existing servlets - using MyBatis
- a single pool connection to a Postgresql database via tomcat's server context.xml configuration.

This ensures that the all the servlets share a common application pool.

I'm adding database analysis loggging to the system, using pgBadger.  The analysis the database log output.
If I was setting this system up new I would likely have created users per servlet and I could use the username to identify the servlet SQL statements called.

As I am using Mybatis to create my Java Objects from the Database, the SQL from each servlet is identical.

Can I possible use the datasource connection's application name parameter for each servlet, but still have a common pool?

In other words: is it possible to use a common database connection pool, but have different application name passed onto the database?
Or indeed can I use the same pool and use a different username?

Does both these constraints mean that the connection pools need to be multiplied by the number of servlets?

Comment: why you are trying to separate by servlet ?

Comment: I'm added new servlets to a working system of 10 or more servlets.  These new servlets will be accessing the existing database.  I'm using MyBatis generated SQL and hand written SQL (still within MyBatis).  When looking at the performance of the system I will want to pick the highest load SQL statements to optimise these first.  It makes it easier to know which Servlet is calling the SQL from mybatis "GetRowFromDatabaseTable" 10,000 times an hour and which is calling it 10.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel With analysis of the Postgresql logs I can pick the worst performing SQL, yet the system I'm inherited does not identify which servlet is at the end of the connection.  I am adding a servlet to an existing heavily used system and I cannot profile the new servlet without id'ing the connection in the log - like I said I'd use db username normally.  I'd use a new connection in the context.xml in each servlets but the current system uses a single connection in the server's context.xml and I'm concerned about changing the system to use a pool per servlet.

Comment: I am not sure you have any other choice. A `javax.sql.DataSource` has a `getConnection` method that takes a username + password, but those are usually not pooled, so if you need a username to distinguish between connections and you want pooling, then you'll need a connection pool per servlet.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for that, it looks like it's going to be a bigger unplanned task than I had hoped for.  Or rather a task I wanted to do at a later stage when I started looking at postgres server clustering